# How to find 3G signal strength when connection is already established by pppd?

Tags: linux, networking, ppp

I want signal strength information when pppd connection is already running. I am running pppd on embedded Linux environment and 3g modem manufactured Cinterion.

I knew commands from which i am able to know signal strength but when my pppd connection is running it will block /dev/ttyUSB and because of that i am not able to find signal strength information.

Need further more information please tell me.

Thanks in Advance, Ravi Bhuva.